# How to save canvas data, submit it to the interface, and make it available for secondary editing

Tags: javascript, canvas

After editing a text in canvas, how to submit the image to the server and edit the text / line again.
One way is to save each image or text as a JSON entry, save the JSON data when saving, and load the canvas according to JSON. The theory should be feasible. Do not know if there is a better solution or mature JS library to achieve this effect?
[image]

Comment: Yes, you have to store the composition steps if you want to be able to alter them later. The format is up to your choice, like some custom JSON, or you can look into some (typically) vector graphics format, like SVG. To be honest this question leaves a lot for imagination.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve most only standard API. [Like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData):

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
/* something draw with ctx */

let bytes = ctx.getImageData().data;
```

`bytes` includes raw image data as byte array. You can post this to server directly, but it seems good to compress as png or jpeg, and encode to base64. Compression process depends on external library, but [base64 encoding exists standard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64).

Answer (score 0):

thx,I think I found what I wanted, I found fabricjs and used it